# Pass parameters jenkins MultiBranch Action Triggers Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

I am using this jenkins MultiBranch Action Triggers Plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/multibranch-action-triggers-plugin

I need to trigger another job when a branch is deleted. The trigger is working fine, however from this new job that gets triggered I need to pass the branch name that was deleted. So I am having a hard time finding out how to pass parameters from a deleted branch to the job that was triggered.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the plugin:

> Branch/Pipeline name value is passed to the job by the parameter named "SOURCE_PROJECT_NAME". This parameter will have the name of the Pipeline/Branch which is created by Multi Branch Pipeline. For example if you only have master branch in your repository, this value will be "master".

So go to your pipeline which is run after a branch is deleted, go to configure -> general, and check the "this project is parameterized" box. fill the form as below:
[image: Parameter Configuratiion]

In pipeline script, try to print `SOURCE_PROJECT_NAME`

```
node { 
     println(SOURCE_PROJECT_NAME)
}
```

This should print out your deleted branch name.